# Two concerns about this piece of news

Tags: word-meaning

> "The weather in the southern Indian Ocean is much clearer today than the past couple of days, allowing for the full spectrum of electronic and visual of search capability," -Commander William J. Marks, spokesman for the U.S. 7th Fleet, said in an email.

The source is [here](http://mobile.reuters.com/article/topNews/idUSBREA2701720140323?irpc=932)

1. When it says: (... allowing for the full spectrum of electronic and visual of search capability,..) isn't the second "of" just a typo? Or perhaps could we omit it?  I mean it should be something like (... allowing for the full spectrum of electronic and visual search capability, ...)
2. Spectrum is a difficult word to digest.  Even after looking at Longman that writes easy I cannot figure it out.  Would you simplify it?

Comment: [Definition of spectrum](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/spectrum_1?q=spectrum). it's a technical word, and what you do not understand is not clear in what you say.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes, the second *of* is improper. It is probably a typographical error, but it may be a 'slip of the tongue' on the part of Cdr. Marks.
2. *Spectrum* was originally a Latin word meaning *appearance*, and in English *spectrum* originally meant the *visible spectrum*—the range of electromagnetic frequencies which the human eye can perceive, approximately 430–790 THz. Physicists extend the bare word *spectrum* to the entire range of electromagnetic frequencies, including radiation at frequencies above and below the visible spectrum. From this scientific usage, the word has been further extended to denote *any* range of values, and that is how Cdr. Marks uses the word, to denote the entire range of capabilities which might be employed in the search—which might include sonar and computer processing and other techniques in addition to electronic and visual detection.